# How to set the data types when creating a view in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a narrow formatted table and want to create a wide formatted view. When I create the view, I want to use the ORACLE_DTYPES column in the table to set the data type in the view. I included the ORACLE_DTYPES column because VALUE is a mix of strings, integers, and floats. My current issue is that my `CASE` statement will return a number or char, so I get the following error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR
```

**Question:** How can I modify my view statement so that I can return the proper data type for the view?

*Sample table*

| REVISION | COLOR | PARAMETER | VALUE | ORACLE_DTYPES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | blue | param1 | 1 | INTEGER |
| 0 | blue | param2 | 1.23 | FLOAT |
| 0 | blue | param3 | hello | VARCHAR2(50) |
| 0 | blue | param4 | there | VARCHAR2(50) |
| 0 | red | param1 | 3 | INTEGER |
| 0 | red | param2 | 1.4032 | FLOAT |
| 0 | red | param3 | how are | VARCHAR2(50) |
| 0 | red | param4 | you | VARCHAR2(50) |
| 1 | blue | param1 | 5 | INTEGER |
| 1 | blue | param2 | 5.4122 | FLOAT |
| 1 | blue | param3 | another | VARCHAR2(50) |
| 1 | blue | param4 | word | VARCHAR2(50) |
| 2 | red | param1 | 10 | INTEGER |
| 2 | red | param2 | 9.13 | FLOAT |
| 2 | red | param3 | dog | VARCHAR2(50) |
| 2 | red | param4 | cat | VARCHAR2(50) |

*Create table*

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    "REVISION" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "COLOR" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "PARAMETER" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "VALUE" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "ORACLE_DTYPES" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ENABLE
)
```

*Create view*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview AS
SELECT
    "REVISION",
    "COLOR",
    MAX(CASE "PARAMETER" WHEN 'param1' THEN
            CASE "ORACLE_DTYPES"
                WHEN 'FLOAT' THEN TO_NUMBER("VALUE")
                WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN TO_NUMBER("VALUE")
                ELSE TO_CHAR("VALUE")
            END
        ELSE NULL END),
    MAX(CASE "PARAMETER" WHEN 'param2' THEN
            CASE "ORACLE_DTYPES"
                WHEN 'FLOAT' THEN TO_NUMBER("VALUE")
                WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN TO_NUMBER("VALUE")
                ELSE TO_CHAR("VALUE")
            END
        ELSE NULL END),
    MAX(CASE "PARAMETER" WHEN 'param3' THEN
            CASE "ORACLE_DTYPES"
                WHEN 'FLOAT' THEN TO_NUMBER("VALUE")
                WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN TO_NUMBER("VALUE")
                ELSE TO_CHAR("VALUE")
            END
        ELSE NULL END),
    MAX(CASE "PARAMETER" WHEN 'param4' THEN
            CASE "ORACLE_DTYPES"
                WHEN 'FLOAT' THEN TO_NUMBER("VALUE")
                WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN TO_NUMBER("VALUE")
                ELSE TO_CHAR("VALUE")
            END
    ELSE NULL END)
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY
    "REVISION", "COLOR"
ORDER BY
    "REVISION", "COLOR"
```

The final table should look like this with desired data types:

| REVISION | COLOR | param1 | param2 | param3 | param4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | blue | 1 | 1.23 | hello | there |
| 0 | red | 3 | 1.4032 | how are | you |
| 1 | blue | 5 | 5.4122 | another | word |
| 2 | red | 10 | 9.13 | dog | cat |

```
data types:
REVISION NUMBER
COLOR VARCHAR
param1 NUMBER
param2 NUMBER
param3 VARCHAR
param4 VARCHAR
```

Comment: It seems that you are attempting to convert to a specific data type based on data in a Record.  Within a record for a column you cannot convert one record in the same column to a Varchar2 and then for a different record in the result set convert to a Date or a NUMBER.  Each COLUMN must have the SAME data type.  I believe that is the issue you are having.  A column must either be a NUMBER or a DATE or a Varchar etc... You cannot then return a record for that column as a different type for other records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those ugly issues with EAV schemas. Dynamically determining column types is probably only doable like this with dynamic sql (read: in a procedure).

Instead, because your `parameter` column appears to be 1:1 with your `oracle_dtypes` column, suggesting that `oracle_dtype` is an attribute of `parameter`, consider hard coding directly in your sql instead of the route you are headed where you are shoe-horning this metadata into your table (where it's not even properly normalized).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview AS
SELECT
    "REVISION",
    "COLOR",
    MAX(CASE "PARAMETER" WHEN 'param1' THEN TO_NUMBER("VALUE") ELSE NULL END),
    MAX(CASE "PARAMETER" WHEN 'param2' THEN TO_NUMBER("VALUE") ELSE NULL END),
    MAX(CASE "PARAMETER" WHEN 'param3' THEN TO_CHAR("VALUE") ELSE NULL END),
    MAX(CASE "PARAMETER" WHEN 'param4' THEN TO_CHAR("VALUE") ELSE NULL END),
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY
    "REVISION", "COLOR"
ORDER BY
    "REVISION", "COLOR"
```

That obviously doesn't give you the flexibility you were shooting for, but

1. given the limitations of an RDBMS, you were overshooting
2. If you added a new parameter (and its dtype), you would have to edit this view anyway, so no real loss

If my assumption about the 1:1 nature of `parameter` and `oracle_dtype` columns isn't correct, then the answer is just *"No, this simply isn't possible to hold more than one type in a single column"*.